# XsltTransform System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Expression must evaluate to a node-set.'

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I`m having problem with my **XSLT - Transformation**. This is how I create **XSLT** class

```
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
resolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

var xslt = new XslTransform();
xslt.Load(_xslPath, resolver);

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(myXml))
{
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(sr);

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var argList = new XsltArgumentList();
        var doc2 = File.ReadAllText("D:\\test\\Doc2.xml");
        using (StringReader sr2 = new StringReader(doc2))
        {
            XPathDocument doc2XPath = new XPathDocument(sr2);

            argList.AddParam("doc2", "", doc2XPath);

            xslt.Transform(doc, argList, sw);
        }
    }
}
```

In **XSLT** I have call like:

```
<xsl:call-template name="docBody">
    <xsl:with-param name="doc" select="$doc2/myDoc"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="docNr" select="$doc2Nr"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

When **XSLT** calls Transform it gives me:

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Expression must evaluate to a node-set.'

How I can pass another **XML** as parameter to make it work using only `XslTransform` ?

Comment: Do you get the error on that line `<xsl:with-param name="doc" select="$doc2/myDoc"/>`? Does it work if you use `argList.AddParam("doc2", "", doc2XPath.CreateNavigator());` instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xsltargumentlist-for-style-sheet-parameters-and-extension-objects?view=netframework-4.8#xslt-style-sheet-parameters seems to suggest that an XPathNavigator can work. Or you even might need to use `doc2XPath.CreateNavigator().Select("/")` to pass in a node iterator. I think XslCompiledTransform is a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xsltargumentlist-for-style-sheet-parameters-and-extension-objects?view=netframework-4.8#xslt-style-sheet-parameters, the only .NET type to be seen by `XslTransform` as an XSLT/XPath node-set is an `XPathNodeIterator` so one way to pass your `XPathDocument` in would be to use `doc2XPath.CreateNavigator().Select("/")` as the argument to the `AddParam` method.

Note also that you can pass in URLs to XSLT and then simply use the XSLT `document` function to load a document.

I think XslCompiledTransform is a bit more flexible (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-parameters?view=netframework-4.8) when it comes to passing `XPathDocument`s directly.